# Possible to name query results for future use without a table?

Tags: sql-server, alias, naming

Working in SQL Server 2008 where I only have access to create queries, not tables or views. My question is related to structuring code better.

I have views provided that give me multiple data sets with too much information. I'm attempting to slim the data down for easier use and reference, with requested specifics.

My goal is to have (3) main queries that list all of the data that I need, and to reference and reuse the data for multiple reports.

Query 1 - Incidents: lists all of the detail on a call
Query 2 - Units: lists all of the detail on units responding to a call
Query 3 - 1stUnits: lists all of the detail on 1st responding units only.

Because each of these queries will have multiple CASE statements within them, I was looking for a way to name the actual query, and reference the query in SQL as Qry1Calls or Qry2Units without an extensive subquery, within a query.

I've searched a bit, and found nothing.

It would be a lot easier to select Qry1 and Qry3 where id's match and filter those results by parameters.

Is this possible? I'm transitioning from Access with some SQL to full fledge SQL.

Comment: This isn't clear to me.  Can you show example queries to better describe what you mean?

Comment: I don't have the queries handy, apologies for that. What I can tell you is that I have pages of case statements to convert code #s to descriptions, categories, time ranges on 6-8 different time ranges, etc. I just need to know if you can name a query like an alias and reference that alias to join to another alias.

Comment: If I could create a view with each query, it wouldn't be so difficult.

Comment: From what I understand you are looking to save the results of these queries for re-use. If so, then you can use temporary tables. See these google search results: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sql+server+temp+table&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=pkhkWYTPCpHp8weI_YC4Ag#q=sql+server+temporary+table+example

Comment: Thank you, I've added CTEs, derived and temporary tables to my research and test list for tomorrow. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably *Common Table Expressions (CTEs)*

Read about them here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(SQL.90).aspx

Reference for the `with` keyword and examples here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try tomorrow and see how it works for me. Still learning. I'll post an update then. :)